# Bizarre right bitshift inconsistency

Tags: c, ubuntu, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I've been working with bits in C (running on ubuntu). In using two different ways to right shift an integer, I got oddly different outputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int x = 0xfffffffe;
int a = x >> 16;
int b = 0xfffffffe >> 16;
printf("%X\n%X\n", a, b);
return 0;
}
```

I would think the output would be the same for each: FFFF, because the right four hex places (16 bits) are being rightshifted away. Instead, the output is:

```
FFFFFFFF
FFFF
```

What explains this behaviour?

Comment: You should generally use unsigned types if you're doing bit operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say:

```
int x = 0xfffffffe;
```

That sets `x` to -2 because the maximum value an `int` can hold here is `0x7FFFFFFF` and it wraps around during conversion. When you bit-shift the negative number it gets *weird*.

If you change those values to `unsigned int` it all works out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  unsigned int x = 0xfffffffe;
  unsigned int a = x >> 16;
  unsigned int b = 0xfffffffe >> 16;
  printf("%X\n%X\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting, that the conversion to `signed int` of a value it cannot hold is implementation defined.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good point. I'm sure good compilers with aggressive warnings turned on would also freak out about this.

Comment: It is not "weird" so much as _implementation defined_.  Most implementations perform "sign extension" when right-shifting - that is the "vacated" MSB is left unchanged so that the sign of the value is unchanged.  Some implementations may fill the vacated but with zero - it generally depends whether the machine instruction set has an _arithmetic shift right_ instruction as opposed to a _logic shift right_ instruction.  For processors with both such as x86, it makes sense to use arithmetic shift, but it is not a given.

Comment: @Clifford That's a great explanation and a long-form version of what I meant by "weird".

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you see here has to do with shifting on signed or unsigned integers which give different results.
Shifts on unsigned integers are *logical*. On the contrary, shift on signed integers are *arithmetic*. **EDIT:** In C, it's implementation defined but **generally** the case.

Consequently,

```
int x = 0xfffffffe;
int a = x >> 16;
```

this part performs an arithmetic shift because x is *signed*. And because x is actually negative (-2 in two's complement), x is *sign extended*, so '1's are appended which results in 0xFFFFFFFF.

On the contrary,

```
int b = 0xfffffffe >> 16;
```

0xfffffffe is a litteral interpreted as an *unsigned* integer. Therefore a *logical* shift of 16 results in 0x0000FFFF as expected.

Comment: In C, the behavior of right-shifts on negative values implementation-defined, per C 2018 6.5.7 5.